# Converting DOMString to String in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, dom

I am using javascript to add tooltips for a set of column headers in a displaytag table. I am trying to using an array to map the corresponding description to the header but it's not working.

```
        var columnHeaderCells = document.getElementById("tableMES").getElementsByTagName("thead")[0].rows[0].cells; 

        var myArray = new Array();
        myArray['Seller ID'] = "this is seller ID";
        myArray['Clicks'] = "this is clicks";
        myArray['Sales'] = "this is Sales";

        var i = 0;
        while (columnHeaderCells[i]){

            var cellText = columnHeaderCells[i].textContent;
            //cellText is not text

            //alert(myArray[cellText] + "---" + cellText);

            columnHeaderCells[i].setAttribute('title', myArray[cellText]);

            i++;
        }
```

The problem seem to be that cellText is not a String but a DOMString object and that's why myArray[cellText] returns null instead of getting the array value I want. If I did:.

```
myArray['Seller ID']
```

it would return "this is seller ID"

Any tips on dealing with DOMString and String?

Comment: have you try using toString() as cellText.toString()?

Comment: Yes, and it didn't make a difference

Comment: tried adding +"" to force it into it?

Answer (score 0):

In IE `textContent` should work (on a text node!), in other browsers, use `nodeValue`.

---

Also:

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray['Seller ID'] = "this is seller ID";
myArray['Clicks'] = "this is clicks";
myArray['Sales'] = "this is Sales";
```

This is not an array. This is an object. Write it like so instead:

```
var myObject = {};
myObject['Seller ID'] = "this is seller ID";
myObject['Clicks'] = "this is clicks";
myObject['Sales'] = "this is Sales";
```

and

```
myObject[cellText]
```

This *should* work.

In JavaScript `Arrays` can only have numeric indexes: `[ "zero", "one", 2, "3" ]`

If you want an associative array (or HashMap or properties or however you want to call them) use an object: `{}`;

Comment: cellText is what is not a string and that is taken from the dom, not the array, so this shouldn't change the end result, but it is indeed a better way to store associative data in js.

Comment: It didn't make a difference but thanks for letting me know about the associative array stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Some stabs in the dark, but try this:

```
var cellText = columnHeaderCells[i].textContent + "";
```

Or this:

```
var cellText = String(columnHeaderCells[i].textContent);
```

Or this:

```
var cellText = [columnHeaderCells[i].textContent].join("");
```

Or this:

```
var cellText = columnHeaderCells[i].textContent.toString();
```

Any one of those should convert it to a JS string.

Comment: Already tried all of these and nothing seems to work, I'm going to looking in nodeValue and firstChild properties of a HTMLTableCellElement object, which columnHeaderCells[i] is

Answer (score 0):

Try `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`.

Comment: Firefox doesn't recognize innerHTML and IE started to used textContext in IE9.